# Does a DBMS store multiple B+ tree on disk for a single table?

Tags: database, b-tree

I am pretty new to database systems and I have come doubts which I could not find answers.

If I am not wrong, the DBMS stores tables and their associative B+ trees on disk, and commonly each table will have a B+ tree based on its primary key.
However if I have a table which contains 2 columns `student_id` and `GPA`, and I want to do a range query on GPAs. It's not able to efficiently perform this query because there's no B+ tree constructed with GPA. My question is how DBMS address problem like this? Does it maintain a B+ tree for every column in your table?

Comment: There's no single answer to your question. The internals of databases are complex, and several organizations are possible. In general, every index, including the primary key map, corresponds to either a B-tree or hash table variant. Hash tables support only equality checks. Trees support a natural order over the (potentially compound) key.

Comment: @Gene Thank for the reply! Does this imply that some DBMS may maintain such data structures for multiple columns on disk for a single table?

Comment: No. It says that we don't know the internal representations of every DBMS, and so there's no single answer to your question. Yes, it's entirely possible that at least one DBMS does something. It's equally as possible that none of them do.